# Intelij Spring project to eclipse Not working

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, intellij-idea

I have created a spring web application in intellij idea 12. and now try to configure the same project in eclipse 
for that i choose export to eclipse. and when i import that project into eclipse using import project from existing source
It says full of error for spring libray file missing.  I have included all the spring mvc libraries from .m2/repository (Intellij)
but it says error in `import javax.servlet.http.httpservletrequest cannot be resolved`

Please anyone help me to run the idea spring project into eclipse using tomccat 7. Please provide any suggestions. I am using maven
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you configured the project build path?

Comment: You are probably missing servlet library.

Comment: No. I did not configure

Comment: I added servlet jar but it does not show any output. Tocat started but says 404

Answer (score 2):

[HttpServletRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) is a part of Java servlet API. You can use different dependencies to resolve that. In your case, I think the best choice will be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

It's avaliable from [maven central repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0). Because, as you said, you're using maven, all you need to do is to put dependency described above to your pom.xml

> I have included all the spring mvc libraries from .m2/repository (Intellij)

I'm not sure you're resolving your dependencies via maven. ".m2/repository" has nothing to do with Intellij, it's your local maven repository.

Comment: I added servlet jar but it does not show any output. Tocat started but says 404

Answer (score 0):

Install the plugin m2e to manage maven project into eclipse [m2e](http://eclipse.org/m2e/)

Using "import project from existing source" will not manage the dependencies store into maven